# Why Text is not Colored when added a style element

Tags: html, styles, font-family

Trying to add a color and Font family within a H1 tag together using style still it not works.Color property does not have any effect on my current line

```
<h1 align="center" style=" font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"color:#0000FF">The Island Resort and Spa 
    <br>Welcome to Holiday Speciala</h1>
```

Why Text is not colored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you separate between css properties using `"` and it is wrong the style attribute written as follow `style=""` and inside the double quotes you should write you css properties and separate between them using `;` like this

```
style=" font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0000FF"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a little typo there..

```html
<h1 align="center" style=" font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0000FF">The Island Resort and Spa 
    <br>Welcome to Holiday Speciala</h1>
```